# Alignment change when adding a new tab in Luci OpenWRT

Tags: html, lua, openwrt, luci

I am trying to `add a new tab in Luci` . I added a new file `page.lua` with following code in /lua/luci/controller/admin

```
module("luci.controller.admin.page",package.seeall)
function index()
entry({"admin","content"},template("admin-page/pagedetail"),_("Page"),20).index=true
end
```

and in view `pagedetail.htm`

```
<%+header%>
<h1></h1>
<%+footer%>
```

But when i add this content , the new created "page" tab is merge with `logout` tab in main page . When i inspect the values , i can see that

```
<a class="logout" style="" href="">Page
<img src="/luci-static/resources/cbi/logout.png" style="float:right"></a>
```

why my new tab is acessing the `class="logout"`? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding a drop down tab .

```
entry({"admin","newtab"},alias("admin","newtab","tab"),_("newtab"),20).index=true
```

and you can add child elements to this newtab by adding another entry function with template or cbi methods .